# Replace URI value in a @font-face CSS rule with cssutils

Tags: python, css, python-3.x

I would like to replace the URL value of a @font-face CSS rule with [cssutils](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/docs/css.html).

My style.css looks like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:"Palatino";
    font-style:normal;
    font-weight:normal;
    src : url("../font/Palatino.ttf");
}

p {
    # some stuff
}
```

and my python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cssutils

sheet = cssutils.parseFile('style.css')

for rule in sheet:
    # Pick up only @font-face rules
    if rule.type == cssutils.css.CSSFontFaceRule.FONT_FACE_RULE:

        ## TODO
        ## replace the src value
```

How can I replace the URI value of the rule `rule` to something like `url(../font/Palatino.otf) format('opentype')`?

I was hoping to use a `cssutils` class method ([like this one](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/docs/css.html#urivalue)) which would allow me something like: `class_method_to_replace_url(object, new_url)`, but I can't really make it work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in the [example of the docs](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/README.html#example), you could iterate over `rule.styles` to find the `src` property, and for that replace it's value. Here is an example:

```
import cssutils

sheet = cssutils.parseFile('style.css')
for rule in sheet:
    if rule.type == cssutils.css.CSSFontFaceRule.FONT_FACE_RULE:
        for property in rule.style:
            if property.name == 'src':
                property.value = "url(../font/Palatino.otf) format('opentype')"
print(sheet.cssText.decode())
```